# Networking wifi Debian one way connection

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, debian

On a Debian server that is connected to local network through wifi nic I have the following problem

Server WiFi ip : wlan0 192.168.1.117
Server cable ip : eth0 192.168.1.100

FROM THE SERVER

I am able to ping -I wlan0 192.168.1.1 (the default gateway)

I am able to ping -I wlan0 8.8.8.8

FROM CLIENT

When I ping the server on 192.168.1.117 I get Connection Timeout

When I browse to the webpage 192.168.1.117 hosted on the server I get a Timeout

If I connect the server on the network through cable I am able to ping the server through 192.168.1.117

/etc/network/interfaces content

```
  # Wired adapter #1
  auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1

# Wireless adapter #1
 allow-hotplug wlan0
 iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.117
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp


auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf Content

```
  ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
  update_config=1

  network={
  ssid="DDkn1sS"
  psk="KASOS123456"
  proto=RSN
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  pairwise=CCMP
  auth_alg=OPEN
  }
```

ifconfig results

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 96:87:5f:a4:dd:b6
      inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::9487:5fff:fea4:ddb6/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:711 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:26448 (25.8 KiB)  TX bytes:91643 (89.4 KiB)
      Interrupt:114

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

 wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:ca:82:d5:01
      inet addr:192.168.1.117  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::2c0:caff:fe82:d501/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:13721 (13.3 KiB)  TX bytes:828 (828.0 B)
```

arp -a results on client pc trying to connect to server

```
  Interface: 192.168.1.5 --- 0x2
 Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
 192.168.1.1           6c-2e-85-16-4c-f0     dynamic
 192.168.1.100         96-87-5f-a4-dd-b6     dynamic
 192.168.1.117         96-87-5f-a4-dd-b6     dynamic
 192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
 224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
 224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
 239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
 255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

EDIT 1

results of ip route on server

```
ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.100
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.117
```

If I look in my router settings I can see the mac address of the WiFi nic in the association tabel

I used

```
 route del -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth0
```

on the server but  no avail.

Comment: I think your server or both server and client don't connect to the wireless network. The ARP table clearly shows that `192.168.1.117` is mapped to `eth0` hardware address. My guess is the ping works only because it gets routed over `eth0` instead. Debug the server wireless connection when `eth0` is unplugged or delete routes for `eth0` (explore command `ip route`). Then update us with more information (also add the output of `ip route`).